# converting data back into a string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

So I have this:

```
  NSData *charlieSendData = [[charlieImputText stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I know how to convert NSStrings to data but how I convert data back to an NSString?

Elijah

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use `NSString`'s `-initWithData:encoding:` initializer method.

```
NSData *charlieSendData = [[charlieImputText stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSString *charlieSendString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:charlieSendData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 12):

Use NSString's initWithData method:

```
NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:charlieSendData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Convert String to Data format

```
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)
```

Converting back from Data to string

```
 let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
```

In Objective-c

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataToConvert encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: the question was about Obj-C, not Swift

Comment: added code for objective-c as wel